# Find an equation of plane that contains lines and is perpendicular to the plane

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find an equation of plane that contains line $x=-2+3t$, $y=4+2t$, $z=3-t$
and is perpendicular to the plane $x-2y+z=5$.

Give final answer in the form of $ax+by+cz=d$.

Comment: OK, the normal vector of the plane should be perpendicular to the line and also to the normal vector of the other plane. Do you know how to find a vector perpendicular to the two given vectors?

Comment: <3,2,-1> x <1,-2,1> = <0,-4,-8>

Comment: That's right. Here is your normal vector. (You might want to multiply it by -1 to look more "natural".) Now take any point on the line (and hence on the plane) and use it to find $d$.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the guidance, it helped me a lot.